# Run function on WxPython GUI thread

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

part-time C# programmer here trying to learn Python.

I am looking to be able to, from another thread, set up a function that will be run on the GUI thread in WxPython. Currently the only way I can think of doing this is to push the function onto some cross-thread-synchronized list, then have a timer firing every few milliseconds (on the GUI thread) that checks the list and runs any functions that have been pushed onto it. I was wondering if there was instead a more canonical way of doing this, similar to `BeginInvoke` in .NET.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`wx.CallLater`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.CallLater-class.html) and [`wx.CallAfter()`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx-module.html#CallAfter).

Comment: Thank you! wx.CallAfter() was exactly what I was looking for.